# How to use two rows to create a new row in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a sample of a df I am working with. I am particularly interested in these two columns `rusher` and `receiver`.

```
     rusher     receiver
0   A.Ekeler      NaN
1   NaN        S.Barkley
2   C.Carson      NaN
3   J.Jacobs      NaN
4   NaN         K.Drake
```

I want to run a groupby that considers all of these names in both columns (because the same name can show up in both columns).

My idea is to create a new column `player`, and then I can just groupby `player`, if that makes sense. Here is what I want my output to look like

```
      rusher    receiver        player
0   A.Ekeler      NaN          A.Ekeler
1   NaN        S.Barkley       S.Barkley
2   C.Carson      NaN          C.Carson
3   J.Jacobs      NaN          J.Jacobs
4   NaN         K.Drake        K.Drake
```

I would like to take the name from whichever column it is listed under in that particular row and place it into the `player` column, so I can then run a groupby.

I have tried various string methods but I don't know how to work around the `NaN`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `fillna`

```
df['player'] = df['rusher'].fillna(df['receiver'])
```